# Can Leibniz's law be used to define identity?

Tags: identity, circularity

In the identity entry of the Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, section 2, first paragraph (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/#LogiIden), it says that it would be a circular definition.

> only picks out identity uniquely if “what is true of x” is understood to include “being identical with x”; otherwise it is too weak. Circularity is thus not avoided.

What I didn't understand is why it's too weak.

Comment: Because if being identical is not included then one can very well have two numerically distinct things of which all available whats are true or false simultaneously.

Comment: @Conifold If I define identity as all its properties not counting the identity itself being true or false simultaneously, then by definition what you say is not possible, right?

Comment: Defining something by "its properties..."  is circular, not to mention that "all properties" is too vague without qualifications.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the wording was not the clearest, but the idea is quite simple. Let us examine the sentence: "If everything that is true of [x] is true of [y], then [x] and [y] are identical". If we are to assert that the predicate "is identical to x" is true of [x], then, under the given sentence, it should also be true of y, resulting in circularity *if* you are using this as a definition of identity.

In essence, the "everything true of x" portion of the statement includes being *identical* to x as one of the many things that are true of x and hence would also have to be true of y; yet how can you know this to be true of y without having defined it in the first place?

Comment: And couldn't identity predicates be excluded from the definition? That is, the definition is "If everything that is true of [x] except the identity predicates is true of [y], then [x] and [y] are identical." Thus there is no longer circularity.

Comment: @Kirby The statement was directed at Libnez's law (not the converse as I have stated above). Libnez's law states the following: (x = y) -> [T(x) -> T(y)]. So, even if we restrict the truth predicate, it would only be a necessary condition and hence not sufficient to define identity. To elucidate, if I state that two apples are identical, I need to see if what is true of A is true of B, if I find this to be true, then I have satisfied the necessary condition for Libnez's law. Yet, this dosen't show identity unless I assume the identity predicate is within the scope of "what is true of x".

Comment: To avoid this, I could simply use the converse of Libnez law and restrict the scope of "what is true of x" as you have recommended, resulting in the logical statement [T(x) -> T(y)] -> (x = y) (if I conjoin this with Libnez law, it would become a biconditional). In this case, restricting the truth function to a curtailed domain would not result in it being too weak, though other problems may arise depending on your restriction (as mentioned in the article).